# SelectKBest gives memory error even with sparse matrix

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have some spreadsheet data that is over a GB and wanting to use random forest. Following some other questions on here I was able to tune the algorithm to work with my data but unfortunately to get the best performance I needed to do one hot encoding of a categorical feature and now my input matrix has over 3000 features resulting in a memory error.

I'm trying to reduce these features so I'm using SelectKBest with chi2 which according to docs will deal with my sparse matrix but I'm still getting memory error.

I tried using to_sparse with fill_value=0 which seems to reduce memory footprint, but when I call fit_transform I get memory error

MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      4 Y_sparse = df_processed.loc[:,'Purchase'].to_sparse(fill_value=0)
      5 
----> 6 X_new = kbest.fit_transform(X_sparse, Y_sparse)

```
kbest = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression, k = 5)
X_sparse = df_processed.loc[:,df_processed.columns != 'Purchase'].to_sparse(fill_value=0)
Y_sparse = df_processed.loc[:,'Purchase'].to_sparse(fill_value=0)

X_new = kbest.fit_transform(X_sparse, Y_sparse)
```

I simply want to reduce the 3000 features to something more manageable say 20 that correlate well with my Y values (continuous response)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error on everything is because to do anything in Pandas or sklearn, the entire dataset has to be loaded in memory along with all the other data from temporary steps.

Instead of doing one hot encoding, try binary encoding or hashing encoding. One-hot-encoding has a linear growth rate `n` where `n` is the number of categories in a categorical feature. Binary encoding has `log_2(n)` growth rate so you will be able to avoid memory error. If not, try hashing encoding.